# ggpattern::geom_rect_pattern is very slow

Tags: r, ggplot2, benchmarking, ggpattern

The code below is very slow (and possibly does not even run - I have not waited for it to finish yet). Is there a way of speeding it up?

```
library(ggpattern); library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_rect_pattern(aes(xmin = 5000, xmax = 10000, ymin = 0, ymax = 15000), pattern = 'stripe', fill = 'white', colour = 'white')
```

Comment: The code you have here is plotting 53,000 large patterned rectangles directly on top of each other. You are therefore drawing a couple of million polygons, of which you will only see the final rectangle. Is that what you intended? You would get the same visual result in a few hundred milliseconds if you switch the first line to `tail(diamonds, 1)`